# Small GUI Font Size with External Monitor

Tags: gui, external-monitor

I've recently upgraded my notebook **from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04.1**. After the upgrade, I experience this:

- If an external monitor is attached during logging in or turning on, I get very small font sizes on the top bar, desktop icons, and activities. I can resolve this manually every time by going to Settings -> Universal Access and then enable and disable LargeText. (LargeText is disabled by default.)
- If I log in without an external monitor, the font size is normal, even when I attach a monitor after logging in.

Both built-in and external displays have resolutions 1920×1080.

This is annoying, so is there any way to log in with the attached monitor and get normal font sizes?

Comment: There is currently a bug in mutter with font scaling. See the post I marked as duplicate for information on the bug. Temporary workarounds are available there.

Comment: Thanks @vanadium. It seems that this post tackles the same issue. However, it currently doesn't have the selected answer nor it offers more than hacks and workarounds (possibly because there is none).

Comment: I said temporary workarounds are there, so you should not expect anything else. It is a bug, so essentially we have to wait until it is fixed, lacking the coding skills ourselves.